# Can I develop the regular chrome-optimized websites in Windows 10 Embedded OS?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, point-of-sale

I'm currently developing a web-based POS, and I'm looking to purchase a touchscreen POS machine which comes with Windows 10 Embedded.

I have read somewhere that it cannot just download any software, Chrome included, so I fear that even if I optimize for IE instead, it might not also be able to use the usual technologies utilized in most websites such as: SQLite, Node.JS, Sockets.IO, etc.

Anyone who had tried using Win 10 Embedded before, is it the same as your regular PC Windows?

Thanks

Comment: If all you need is a browser, why don't you use Linux for your POS application?  Much more reliable, in my experience.

Comment: I think so too, but the problem is the Win Embedded 10 comes included as a package. Even if I remove it and install Linux instead, I'm not sure whether the hardware is configurable enough to let me install another OS, that's why as much as possible I'd like to stick to whatever OS that it comes with

Comment: You could e.g. boot Fedora and try a live system, or boot into CentOS and look if the graphical installer supports the touchscreen.  That is what I usually do to check new HW.  I have not seen POS hardware in a long time that would not run LInux...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no browser(Chrome,IE...) included in Windows 10 IoT Core and also you can't install it.

You may need develop a UWP-style browser by yourself. If you like do this you can reference [IoT Browser Sample](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/iotbrowser).

As for your user case(POS machine), **Windows 10 IoT Enterprise** is the best choice because:

> Windows 10 IoT Enterprise brings the capabilities of Windows 10
>   Enterprise to a wide range of industry devices across retail,
>   manufacturing, health, finance and other industries. Windows 10 IoT
>   Enterprise supports both Universal Windows apps and Classic Windows
>   applications...

For more information about different Windows 10 IoT Editions you can reference  [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/WindowsForBusiness/windows-iot).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!